# Asp.net Core Caching + IE 11 Results in Cached Responses

Tags: internet-explorer, asp.net-core, caching, iis, internet-explorer-11

I am having a tough time with Caching, First I am getting problems with Google Chrome caching the front end reactjs code every though I added a hash to the javascript and css file(it seems like the index.html file is being cached??).

Now IE 11 seems to be caching my api called. For instance I load up IE 11 and do a request and then hit F5 and look at the network tab I will see that the requests will be "Received From Cache" this is always shown even if I know 100% the data from the api has changed.

No other browser has this issue.

[image]

Comment: you shuold find your answer here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I saw that posting but still confused what to choose, As like in my scenario you literally make a "choice" then you control + F5 and your previous choice will be still shown so the only option that I saw there is "no cache" which would give immediate changes back to the user(as eerything is like age and time based which would not help)

Comment: For my projects, I create a NoCacheAttribute that I put on controllers or methods, depending on my needs.  Like this, I can control which actions can be cached or not.

Comment: Could you post that code up?

Comment: did you find our answer useful? or didi you find another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control your cache stategy using this attribute on your controller or methods:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public sealed class NoCacheAttribute : ResponseCacheAttribute
    {
        public NoCacheAttribute()
        {
            Duration = 0;
            NoStore = true;
            Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None;
        }
    }
```

And then use this attribute where needed:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [NoCache]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        ... you code here
    }
```

You can also add some parameters to your attribute to finetune your cache strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the cache policy on action using below code

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
```

or globally

```
services.AddMvc(options => {
    options.Filters.Add(new ResponseCacheAttribute() { NoStore = true, Location =  ResponseCacheLocation.None });
})
```